# Proper syntax for nested if statements within for loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Pardon my stupid question, but I just started learning Javascript and HTML by myself yesterday. I am trying to replicate a type-racer sort of game, and can't seem to be able to complete a for loop due to an if statement within it.

See the following:

```
    <script>
        var current = document.getElementById('currentWord');
        function inputMatch(){
            var input = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;
            if(input.length > current.innerHTML.length){
                current.className = "currently-wrong";
            }
            else{
                for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                    if(input[i] != current.innerHTMl[i]){
                        current.className = "currently-wrong";
                    };
                    else{
                        current.className = "currently-correct";
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The word that is supposed to be typed is named **current**

I am fetching the user input in a variable named **input**

I want to iterate through the **input** to see if it matches with **current**. If it matches so far, I wish to change the class to "currently-correct" and otherwise, I wish to change it to "currently-wrong".

I don't know any way of debugging other than placing an alert(i) within the for loop.

When I do so, there is no output. if I remove the else statement and keep the alert(i), the only output are distinct "0"s, which implies that i remains at 0 and does not iterate.

If I remove the if statement AND the else statement, the output is correct as I type in the input.

Namely, if I type

"a" -> 0

"p" -> 0, 1

"p" -> 0, 1, 2

"l" -> 0,1,2,3

"e" -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

This is the expected output/alert, but only works if I remove the if statement. Any suggestions on debugging this?

Comment: The `;` after the `}` in the inner `if` is wrong.

Comment: @MauriceNino Thank you for suggesting the break, I did not think of that. However, even after changing to use `let` and `const` , as well as removing the `;` , it doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: I converted my comments into an answer with a runnable snippet @beepbeepboop123123

Comment: Also check my edit for a prettier version @beepbeepboop123123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use let and const instead of var to reduce unwanted side-effects. Also there should not be a ; after the if brackets.

And when the if statement matches, meaning that the input is wrong, there is no need for further checking (in fact it will also result in errors if you only type one wrong letter in the middle). So just hop out of the loop by using break;

```js
const current = document.getElementById('currentWord');

function inputMatch(){
  const input = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;

  if(input.length > current.innerHTML.length){
    current.className = "currently-wrong";
  }
  else{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      if(input[i] != current.innerHTML[i]) {
        current.className = "currently-wrong";
        break;
      }
      else {
        current.className = "currently-correct";
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
.currently-wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
.currently-correct {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="currentWord">apple</div>
<input id="inputfield" onkeyup="inputMatch()"/>
```

You could however also write it in a prettier way like so:

```js
const current = document.getElementById('currentWord');
const inputField = document.getElementById('inputfield');

const inputMatch = () => {
  const input = inputField.value;

  const matches = current.innerHTML.startsWith(input);
  current.className = matches ?  "currently-correct" : "currently-wrong";
}
```

```css
.currently-wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
.currently-correct {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="currentWord">apple</div>
<input id="inputfield" onkeyup="inputMatch()"/>
```